# Font Awesome HTML -> .png icons

Tags: fonts, icon, css

What is the easiest way to produce several of .png images of icons generated with Font Awesome and some simple CSS styling?

I need to generate some social media icons that will be included in an email template. I chose to use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/download) because it has icons for most social media brands, including Mastodon.

```
<i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
<i class="fa-brands fa-mastodon"></i>
<i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
<i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
```

| [image: [YouTube Icon] [Mastodon Icon] [Facebook Icon] [GitHub Icon]] |
| --- |
| Unstyled Icons produced with Font Awesome and the HTML above |

Because of many quirks in email clients, I think it's better to include the icons as .png images (as opposed to rendering them with html and a font).

Using this [simple helper tool](https://www.simunity.net/), I've decorated the icons with css to color them, add a rounded background, and add a drop shadow

```
<i class="fa-brands fa-youtube" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33) 1.5px 2.6px 4.5px; box-sizing: content-box; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 10%; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></i>
<i class="fa-brands fa-mastodon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33) 1.5px 2.6px 4.5px; box-sizing: content-box; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 10%; background-color: #6364FF;"></i>
<i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33) 1.5px 2.6px 4.5px; box-sizing: content-box; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 10%; background-color: #4260a1;"></i>
<i class="fa-brands fa-github" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 20px; text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33) 1.5px 2.6px 4.5px; box-sizing: content-box; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 10%; background-color: #3c76c4;"></i>
```

| [image: [YouTube Icon] [Mastodon Icon] [Facebook Icon] [GitHub Icon]] |
| --- |
| Icons after being styled with CSS |

Now all I need is a way to go from the icons rendered in the browser to a usable .png file for each. If I just take a screenshot of the icon in firefox, it might work -- except that the background is white (not transparent).

Is there a better tool or workflow in linux to convert each styled Font Awesome icon into a .png with a transparent background?

Comment: See also [Is there any way to save a Web page screenshot with a transparent background?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7838/is-there-any-way-to-save-a-web-page-screenshot-with-a-transparent-background)